# Setting up react-native development environment at M1 Macbook

Tags: ios, react-native, development-environment, apple-m1

**Setting**

- os : Big Sur 11.1
- homebrew : 2.7.1
- node : 14.15.4
- watchman : 4.9.0
- Xcode : 12.3
- cocoapods : 1.8.4

> npx react-native init AwesomeProject

> cd AwesomeProject
> npx react-native start

> cd AwesomeProject
> npx react-native run-ios

**result(err)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIf5l.png)

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwesomeProject.xcworkspace.

until **npx react-native start** there's no error
but **npx react-native run-ios** doesn't work.
I don't get what the problem is. Is Xcode version too high? please help


and how can I build AwesomeProject with Xcode app?. I tried but it failed too.

Comment: The error messages suggests: "To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwesomeProject.xcworkspace." It's probably helpful if you do that and update your question with the Xcode build log.

Comment: hey Seokwon Yoon, were you able to solve this error? I am having the same issue..

Comment: Try "pod install" at ios folder

Comment: Did you solve it? I have this problem

Answer (score -1):

go to applications and right click on Xcode.app. select the get info. fill the check box of open using Rosseta.if yo want to run iOS with terminal do the steps for terminal.app as well.